# TFS 2018 Build NuGet Push

Tags: tfs, build, nuget, push

I am trying to use the new NuGet Extension in TFS Build to push my package to the feed.  My problem is that it creates a temporary config file and that config is empty.  Does anyone know if this is copying the file from some location?

2018-05-04T17:53:57.3567578Z Saving NuGet.config to a temporary config file.

2018-05-04T17:53:57.3723827Z ##[warning]No package sources were found in the NuGet.config file at D:_work\247\Nuget\tempNuGet_5662.config

Comment: `D:_work\247\Nuget\tempNuGet_5662.config` is a weird file name because the drive part isn't followed by `\`

Comment: Could not reproduce your issue with the same TFS2018 version.  Have you tried downgrade  your Nuget task version?

Answer (score 0):

Suggest you first double check if you have followed the demands of Arguments in Nuget task when [Push NuGet packages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/tasks/package/nuget?view=vsts#push-nuget-packages)

Also set `system.debug=true` to [Enable Verbose Debug Mode](https://www.benday.com/2016/09/19/enable-verbose-debug-mode-for-tfs-build-vnext/) with more detail log info for troubleshooting.

Besides, downgrade your Nuget task version and try again. Take a look at this similar issue: [Nuget restore uses temporary config that can change path of packages folder](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/issues/6790)

Answer (score 0):

I finally created a new feed.  That worked so I thought what could be different.  So I then made my old feed's security match my new feed.  That corrected the issue.